# To fund a person

Tags: word-usage

In dictionaries, it says "things" like organizations, projects, events etc. I wonder if we can also say a "person" or "people" are funded if they are provided money for some cause. For example can we say sentences like,

> **The presidential candidate is funded by rich business owners during his campaign.**

> **The Turkish president was funded by EU for him to accept refugees.**

> **LeBron James was funded by Nike to host a camp in China.**

Comment: This is not a question about grammar. It's about idiom - the way we speak. It is common to fund a person's studies or possibly accommodation or medical needs. If you said that you had funded someone, the meaning would be understood (although not the exact purpose of the funds) but it would not be idiomatic. Your first and third example are possible if unlikely. The second is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you. Why do you think the second one is ungrammatical? Do you think I should say "in order for him to..." instead? I can hear native English speakers say "for someone to" instead of "in order for someone to."

Comment: The construction **funded for him to accept...** is not valid - or, at least, extremely awkward. You need to rephrase it. Possibly: **...was funded for his refugee programme.** Much better would be:  **The Turkish President's refugee programme was funded by the EU.** (Although this sidesteps your question.)